# Unable to continue after certificate error i IE

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

I am on a closed HP ILO network, and I am trying to access the web interface (https) of a HP c7000 Onboard Administrator (though I do not believe this is an issue specific to the equipment) through Internet Explorer (8 and 9). From what I gather, the site uses a self-signed certificate. When I enter the IP of the site, IE warns me that "There is a problem with this website's security certificate," with the options to close the webpage or continue

There is no information under "More Information," but when I click it, the address bar says the SSLError=50331648

The problem: When I click on "Continue to this website (not recommended)", I am directed to res://ieframe.dll/, and not to the site.

The sites whose certificates I have already added in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" work fine, but any new sites will just not show.

I recall having tried the following to be allowed in:

- Adding the site to trusted sites
- Disable enhanced internet security
- Check "Allow software to run or install even if signature is invalid"
- Reset all zones to default level
- Disable Protected Mode

Is there anything else I should pay attention to so that I can continue to the site?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue.

Try the following:

Go to the registry and check the following key:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\

Check the value of the key "1400" and change it, if set from "3" to "0".

1400 is the registry key for active scripting, which is needed to be active for the cert-issue.